# System lagging when power plugged

Tags: 18.04, dell, battery, bios

After upgrading the bios to version 1.13.1 I am experiencing system lagging when I plug the power cable. The system is ok if I turn it on on battery or already plugged in. It seems to be affected only for transitions from battery to AC. After a reboot everything goes back to normal. The lagging is about scrolling web pages, watching videos or changing application.

I am using a Dell XPS15 9550 in dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. When running on Windows I am not experiencing this issue.

Since the bios update, when turning the system off, the following message is displayed:

> irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)

It seems that somebody else encountered a similar bios-related problem, suggesting a bios downgrade (https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/ennq4b/dell_xps_9550_bios_downgrade_downgrade_to_1120/).

Since I am not a Ubuntu or Linux expert, before playing with the bios, I would like to ask if somebody has some debugging tool/tip that I can try.

Here are the things that I have already tried, without success:

- disable Secure Boot
- update GPU driver to the one suggested by the vendor
- running with *noapic* or *irqpoll* in GRUB options (suggested in similar questions for irq 16 issue)

Comment: Backup your important data, then enter the BIOS and perform a BIOS reset to factory specs. Reboot and retest. You may have to modify some BIOS settings after the reset, but try without first. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Yes, Dell messes with maximum CPU frequency as a function of AC/battery and if the AC adapter is Dell or other.

Comment: @heynnema I have reset to factory specs but now Ubuntu is not found, as a boot option, and Windows is stack in an automatic repair loop. What shall I do?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There's probably a setting to select BIOS or UEFI. Choose the other option (UEFI). Turn SECURE BOOT off.

Comment: Make sure the disk controller is set to AHCI.

Comment: @heynnema now Windows is showing up, I selected a system restore point created a couple of days ago so it should be fine. How can I make Ubuntu to show up again?

Comment: Good news! What BIOS setting did you end up changing? To fix Ubuntu, the easiest is to try boot-repair... see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for help.

Comment: @heynnema UEFI and SECURE BOOT=off where already selected, I changed the disk controller to AHCI, I am trying now to restore Ubuntu, I will let you know

Comment: boot-repair should be tried first

Comment: @heynnema now Ubuntu is booting but I am back to the starting point, with the lagging issue described before

Comment: I glad that you got it working again. Good job! I don't have any more fixit ideas for you though. Sorry. You could give Dell a call...

Comment: @heynnema thank you for your help, I guess I have to wait until the next Dell BIOS update, hoping it will solve this issue.

Comment: @DougSmythies thank you for your help! I am using a Dell AC adapter. Starting the laptop on battery and plugging in the AC will cause the CPU frequency to go up to its maximum (2.6/2.7 GHz) constantly. I will try to dig deeper but with little hope

Comment: @GiovanniBassi I'd still give Dell a call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of searching and tuning I found the solution.

The problem was caused somehow by TLP (power saving settings).
After balancing battery and AC options (/etc/default/tlp) the lagging disappeared.

Info about TPL [here](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) or TLP man page.